# Metrics missing

Tags: prometheus, promql

We have a metrices suppose

```
(x_metrics{host="1.1.1.1",somelabel="c"})

x_metrics{host="1.1.2.1",somelabel="d"}

x_metrics{host="1.1.2.2",somelabel="e"}
```

All this are data of x_metrics. But now a scenario comes like  `x_metrics{host="1.1.2.1",somelabel="d"}` this particular host stopped coming in prometheus.And I need to write an alert in a generic condition for all the host if stops coming then prometheus should fire an alert.What I ll do in that scenerio??

Please, can anyone guide me in this usecase?

Answer (score 1):

What you can use here is the `up` metric, which will be 0 if the scrape of a host failed. To alert on that you can use the expression `up == 0`.

Comment: Up == 0 expression gives if the entire scrapping from the target stops but suppose the scrapping is working fine only the particular metrices from a different server stops coming to prometheus.

Comment: live saver !!!!